# Cocos2d and grid3d - reset effect after action is complete

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, effects

I am just trying to figure this one out, I have a grid3d CCRipple3D action/effect which appears where it should. Except when it is complete (after 1 second), it "pauses" the effect and leave it in place. All I want is a ripple then it to disappear. This is my code:

```
for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

    id effect = [CCRipple3D actionWithPosition:location radius:180 waves:10 amplitude:20 grid:ccg(60, 60) duration:1]; 

    [self runAction:effect];
}
```

But this leaves a distortion over the layer in that place. I need it to ripple for 1 second and disappear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
id effect = [CCRipple3D actionWithPosition:location radius:180 waves:10 amplitude:20 grid:ccg(60, 60) duration:1];
[someNode runAction:[CCSequence actions:effect,[CCStopGrid action], nil]];
```

In case of older version of cocos2d, use [StopGrid action] instead of [CCStopGrid action].

Probably, OP already found the answer long ago. But still posting the solution, so that anyone can find the answer who arrives here (like I did).

Comment: Thanks, I hadnt found the answer actually so much appreciated! I just left the effect as it was when it had ended, but I can now go back and update this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also met this question while using cocos2d-js 3.0. Thanks to Mesbah's answer, I got this:

```
    var action = cc.shaky3D(3, cc.size(15, 10), 50, false);
    gameBg.runAction( cc.sequence(action, cc.stopGrid()) );
```